# What is a better alternative to the word rickety?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, adjectives

My sentence is "The system was so badly designed that it has now become rickety. Even a minor change could cause the entire system to collapse". Rickety just doesn't seem to fit well.

Comment: "Fragile" might be better in some contexts.

Comment: _Unstable_ should work.

Comment: Which synonyms have you considered and rejected?

Comment: You may say that the system is now "in unstable equilibrium" or that it may "collapse like a house of cards".

Comment: I rather like *rickety* there, actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "*(extremely) unstable*" in place of rickety. When you describe *systems* and *computer-related hardwares and softwares* which are not stable in operation, you use "unstable" which is defined in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unstable):

> (1) Having a strong tendency to change. 
>   (2) Fluctuating; not constant.
>   (3) Fickle.
>   (4) Unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use unstable or unsound.  Fragile would also work.  Rickety seems to fit better when referring to furniture or a stair-case.